# MySql "order by" what the signed user created PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple table with posts.

```
id | name | description | created_by
```

I'm trying to order it by created_by but created_by is the user's id. Let's say number `10` The result should be the posts created by the user who is signed in should be first at the top.

```
ORDER BY created_by
```

The problem is if there are "created_by" data smaller like 1, 2, 3... and these shows up on the top. Any idea how to order posts what the signed user created?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you do not want to order (i.e. sort) but just get all posts created by user with id `10`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
ORDER BY created_by = :logged_in_user DESC
```

A comparison evaluates to `1` when it's true, `0` when it's false, so this will put the ones that match the logged in user ID first.

Comment: will help a lot if you include in your question some sample data and expected output.

Comment: It is working but I have one more question. I have another table where I store who joined these "posts". I need to order that too. Which means first the signed user see his created which is working but then should follow the ones he joined. How can I add an array or something that will define it?

Comment: You can use something like `ORDER BY CASE WHEN created_by = :logged_in_user THEN 1 WHEN follower = :logged_in_user THEN 2 ELSE 3 END`

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need pass @user_id as parameter

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN created_by = @user_id 
              THEN -1
              ELSE created_by
         END
```

Comment: This makes sense too. Thanks

Comment: Is almosst the same as Barmar, but in this case the `-1` make sure the user go first. And the rest of the users are also order it.

Comment: this doesn't really work right for me: ORDER BY CASE WHEN created_by = :created_by THEN -1 ELSE created_at END DESC

Comment: why doesnt work? Any error? maybe `created_by` isnt integer?

Comment: I had DESC and that was messing things up

Comment: I have one more question. I have another table where I store who joined these "posts". I need to order that too. Which means first the signed user see his created which is working but then should follow the ones he joined. How can I add an array or something that will define it?